# How to assign different events to different users in FAAST?

Tags: kinect

I am using a cool tool named [FAAST](http://projects.ict.usc.edu/mxr/faast/) to develop a multi-player Kinect game. However, I can only specify the input event and the corresponding output event(that means if two users did the same action, the output would be same), I don't know how to let different user generated different events with same input event.

For example, if I specify a gesture and its output is "press a" on keyboard.

[image]

Then I got two users in the scene

[image]

Only user 2 (the green one) can successfully generate the event and press a (I use notepad to test)

[image]

I am wondering why this happens and want to know how to let User 1 and User 2 generate different events(maybe User 1 generates "a", and  User 2 generates "b").

Thanks in advance.